# Including header in the class header and implementation?

Tags: c++

I have a class Foo with a corresponding .h and .cpp. Both files make use of an std::string. Should I only `#include <string>` in the header or include it in both files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if the header can get away with a forward declaration then I always use that in the header and the #include in the implementation file. (FD can be used for reference and pointer types).

If they both need it, then i tend to put them in both so that if the header is changed I can remove it from the .h.

Answer (score 2):

I include `<string>` into precompiled header since I don't plan to change it often :). The main rule is: all headers that I won't change often are included into precompiled header: STD, system headers, stable 3rd-party libraries etc. ("often" depends on project size, if project is large "often" tends to "never").

For other headers I voted up [@111111's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9534632/453271)

Answer (score 0):

if you can is better to use forward  declaration because you avoid multiple inclusion, circular inclusion etc..
so when you can use a pointer , put a forward declaration and then includes the file in the .cpp
on all other cases you are forced to include directly on .h (when you  are not using a pointer or reference and when you derive from a class)